# How to move an element in an expandable list SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

There is this initializer that allow you to create a list with children that will expand when clicked on:

```swift
List.init(data:_, children:_, rowContent:_)
```

This works nice and well, however, it does not allow you to move elements of the list which would be possible for a `DynamicViewContent` like a `ForEach`. So is it possible to either modify the list so that it may accept methods like `onMove(perform:_)` or encompass a `ForEach` somehow so that one can move the contents of this list?